# Mod_rewrite how to remove URI segment

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have multiple languages on my web page. Here are link examples:

```
http://myweb.com/en/page_load/about_us
http://myweb.com/en/page_load/testing

http://myweb.com/de/page_load/about_us
http://myweb.com/de/page_load/testing
```

I want to make it shorter like this:

```
http://myweb.com/en/about_us
http://myweb.com/en/testing

http://myweb.com/de/about_us
http://myweb.com/de/testing
```

Currently I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|css|blogg|img|captcha|robots\.txt|sitemap.xml|resources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to merge both rules or what you have in your `.htaccess` is just some initial attempt to do the work you propose?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CodeIgniter's built-in routing.  Try something like this in your `routes.php` config file.

```
$route['en/page_load/:any'] = "en/$1";
$route['de/page_load/:any'] = "de/$1";
```

That should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the `page_load` part, you can just do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page_load/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

If you want to merge both rules, I recommend you first to use `REQUEST_URI` as the `RewriteCond` variable (instead of `$1`, which depends on the `RewriteRule`), and also, if possible, to specify conditions on positive cases instead of negative cases (prefer not using `!` for conditions). I think this way would be more maintainable.